Three dimensional spherical interpolation like trilinear interpolation
Say we have a 5x5x5 grid where a quaternion, q, exists at every point. The objective is to express the distribution of quaternions in a functional form in terms of the positions, i.e. q(x,y,z) = Ax + By + Cz + Ax^2 + ... q(x,y,z) would then allow us to take a curl or spatial derivatives.
If the quantity involved is something that can be broken down into scalar quantities, we can apply trilinear interpolation: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trilinear_interpolation and obtain f(x,y,z). But the closest I can find for quaternion is the spherical linear interpolation, SLERP.
MATLAB's SLERP documentation page says SLERP is "an extension of linear interpolation along a plane to spherical interpolation in three dimensions". However, despite the quaternions may be three-dimensional, SLERP is still in 2D or even 1D. See this figure from MATLAB's SLERP page:

I call it 2D or 1D because it interpolates using only 2 points, whereas the trilinear interpolation can use any number of points in 3D.
So, is there a similar form of SLERP to trilinear interpolation? I tried to search for it but couldn't find it.
Alternatively, if quaternion components can be individually interpolated, then I can perhaps still apply trilinear interpolation. I don't believe this is true, but maybe I just haven't found the right literature on it yet.
